# Delphi Rio 10.3.2 Android FireDac SQLITE unable to open query - same code worked with Delphi Tokyo with same android device

Tags: android, sqlite, delphi, firedac

Here is the very simple code that worked perfectly when compiled with Delphi Tokyo:

```
procedure TfData.DataSend(Memo : TMemo);
var SelectQuery : string;
begin
    // Query simplified, more fields are retreived in original code, but same problem with simple query
    SelectQuery := 'SELECT NUM as "NUM::TEXT" FROM TRACE WHERE DT_SENT is null ORDER BY DT_TRACE';
    YsDbQuerySelect.SQL.Clear;
    YsDbQuerySelect.SQL.Add(SelectQuery);
    YsDbQuerySelect.Prepare;
    try
      YsDbQuerySelect.Open;
      if YsDbQuerySelect.RecordCount > 0 then begin // I get 6 records here
        YsDbQuerySelect.First; // ********** Exception !

        while not YsDbQuerySelect.eof do begin    
         // making a file... code removed, not relevant          
          YsDbQuerySelect.Next;
        end;
        YsDbQuerySelect.Close;
      end
      else begin
        YsDbQuerySelect.Close;
        MesInfo('No data to send');
      end;
    except
      on e : exception do begin
        // Exception displays the annoying error
        MesError(e.Message + ' SLQ : ' + SelectQuery);
      end;
    end;
end;
```

The same simple code running on the same real android device (Zebra TC25) does not work anymore when compiled with Tokyo 10.3.2. The "RecordCount" method returns 6, however, the "First" method trigger an exception : something like "Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset", the original message is in french : "Impossible d'effecteur cette opération sur un ensemble de données fermé"

I can't understand how "RecordCount" can return something while "First" triggers this exception. And there is indeed 6 record in database. I also deleted then recreated them. Same error. 
I tried to play with some options (fetch options and so on) but nothing is working. It's really annoying.

Note also that other operations work properly on the same SQLite database. The device is able to add and delete records using TDFCommand and to display them using TDataSource. Only TDFQuery encounters the error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I deleted the TDFQuery component then I dropped a new one. It's a bit weird but it's working. I think there nothing to do with Delphi Rio but but with corrupted file ?

Comment: This is speculation, not an answer.  "Corrupted file": Sorry, I don't think this can be right, because what file would be "uncorrupted" by deleting and re-inserting the FDQuery?  The only file which would be *changed* would be the .DFM file containing it, and if the properties of the new FDQuery are the same as the one it replaced, the DFM's contents should be the same.

Comment: Don't you note the question mark ? : "corrupted file ?"  So this is a question, not a speculation. And this solved my issue, so I checked the case solved.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you should re-write your code as

```
YsDbQuerySelect.Open;
while not YsDbQuerySelect.eof do begin    
  // making a file... code removed, not relevant          
  YsDbQuerySelect.Next;
end;
YsDbQuerySelect.Close;
```

The reason is that the

```
if YsDbQuerySelect.RecordCount > 0 then begin 
  YsDbQuerySelect.First
```

should be completely unnecessary because a) if the query returns zero records, the `YsDbQuerySelect.eof` will immediately return False so the `while` loop will never execute and b) if the query *does* return any records, the FDQuery's dataset cursor willl be on the first record so the call to `First` is superfluous.

In any case, in general it is bad practice to make a TQuery-like dataset's behaviour dependent of its `RecordCount` variable because it can be unreliable and extrememly inefficient because it can cause the dataset to retrieve all the matching records.

If you absolutely must check that the query returns records and message the user if it does not, simple replace your

```
if YsDbQuerySelect.RecordCount > 0 then begin // I get 6 records here
  YsDbQuerySelect.First; // ********** Exception !
[etc]
```

by

```
if not YsDbQuerySelect.Eof then begin
  // your while not eof loop
end
else begin
  MesInfo('No data to send');
end;
```

Btw, I do not think you should regard what you describe in your own answer as a solution to the problem, because if the behaviour you were getting was due to corruption of the .DFM file (which I doubt), it could just as easily happen again.

Comment: Yes it's weird, but it happens just after I opened my project with Rio for the first time. Maybe something went wrong at that time. I ran several tests since I removed then drop new TFDQuery. I get no error anymore. Anyway thanks for the tip, I use to write queries with another database where you have to test availability and use a  "get first" before using a record. If it's not necessary with Sqlite (or with FireDac), I'll remove it. The recordCount was written just to test that records exist because "first" and "eof" triggered the damn exception :-). Thanks.

Comment: Hi MartynA, please note that this code does not work: YsDbQuerySelect.Open;
while not YsDbQuerySelect.eof do begin ...   As I use to do, you need to call "YsDbQuerySelect.First". Without that, YsDbQuerySelect.eof always returns false.